# Getting mp4 file size before downloading with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I am writing little script to download video files from some websites for my friend and i want to add progress bar to this but the problem is that there is no "content-length" in headers. I have got this.

```
size = requests.head(link["link"], headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
```

And i got this in return:

```
'X-Varnish': 'HV116W137',
'Age': '84',
'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
'Server': 'Apache',
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Via': '1.1 varnish', 
'cache-control': 'max-age=60, public, 
's-maxage=300', 
'Date': 'Tue, 22 Dec 2015 17:31:05 GMT', 
'x-frame-options': 'deny', 
'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

link: http://n-4-15.dcs.redcdn.pl/dcs/o2/tvn/web-content/m/p1/v/4e6cd95227cb0c280e99a195be5f6615/6398d4db-c842-49c7-8d1f-d1018cd0c95b-480p.mp4

I suppose that this is possible as browser can tell how big is file before downloading this.

Comment: Browsers just send the actual request and then read the content-length header. Have you tried making the GET request instead of head?

Comment: Are you sure `link['link']` is the link you provided? When I tried it out, I get - `content-length': '210919787'`

Comment: thanks. so it must be something wrong with link variable.

Comment: @pvg GET request will start downloading the file. So it's not an option as question is to get size before downloading.

Comment: @YohanE I'm afraid you're misinterpreting a comment on a three year old question.

Answer (score 3):

```
size = requests.head(link['link']).headers['Content-Length']
```